# How much are partnerships and LLCs really taxed?

Tags: united-states, business, tax-law, corporate-law, partnership

Based on the IRS website, [partnerships](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/partnerships) and [LLCs being taxed as partnerships](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/llc-filing-as-a-corporation-or-partnership) appear to only file (at the federal level) 1065 forms with schedule K-1 forms (for each partner/member).

If I'm reading things correctly, that means businesses taxed as partnerships are only responsible for the self-employment taxes for each of their partners/members (i.e. their respective FICA contributions). This, in turn, should mean that a partnership's total, federal tax on earnings is 15.3% (as of 2018) so long as each partner makes below $118,500. This seems a little low compared to the alternatives. Are there really no other taxes or fees I'm forgetting about.

*To be clear, this question is only about federal taxation.*

Comment: Also worth noting that if the firm has employees who are not partners/members who owe self-employment taxes in lieu of FICA taxes, that the firm (rather than the partners/members) owe the FICA taxes and withholding taxes on the amounts paid to the employees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really isn't about law, but I'll answer anyway as I've had an LLC for years...

LLC's (other than those taxed as C-Corps) are taxed as pass-through entities. That means that the income is "passed through" to the members based on the ownership share. Each member is then responsible for paying the appropriate taxes. **The business itself is not taxed, nor is it responsible for paying the taxes of its members.**

So yes, they (the members) pay normal income tax, self-employment tax, and any local taxes.

Lets take an example, Example LLC has 2 members Jack and John. Jack is a 75% ownership and John is 25% ownership. During the year the LLC takes in $250,000 in profits. The LLC files schedule K-1 with the IRS attributing $187,500 to Jack and $62,500 to John.

Jack pays taxes on $187,500 of income

- AGI is $177,028
- Standard deduction is $12,000
- Taxable Income is $165,028
- Tax before SET is $34,499
- Self Employment Tax is $20,943
- Total Tax bill: $55,442 (32% Tax Bracket)

John pays taxes on $62,500 of income

- AGI is $58,085
- Standard deduction is $12,000
- Taxable Income is $46,085
- Tax before SET is $6,078
- Self Employment Tax is $8,831
- Total Tax Bill: $14,909 (22%)

This scenario doesn't include local/state taxes that may also be levied, as well as any interest/charges if quarterly payments were not made.

So yes, an LLC with more than one member only needs to file form K-1 identifying with the IRS what portion of the businesses income is attributed to each member. **This is not an obligation to pay any taxes** on the part of the business, it is simply telling the IRS to "expect this much from X member". The IRS then uses K-1 to cross-check the members income tax forms that they file to be sure that they are paying appropriate taxes. If they don't match the member will get a bill (funny though I've never encountered the IRS voluntarily sending refunds if it differs in the members favor).

Comment: Also, to be up to the minute, it is worth noting that as of tax years beginning January 1, 2018, there is a 20% deduction for federal income tax purposes for income earned in a pass through entity (of course, the devil is in the details). My understanding is that this deduction does not impact self-employment taxes, however, and only impacts state income taxation if that is based on federal taxable income.

Comment: @ohwilleke There are a whole bunch of "rules" that aren't set in stone yet about that "20%" deduction, which is why I didn't include it, but good point.

Comment: Also, while it rarely comes up, part of the penalty for failing to issue a K-1 is that an LLC or partnership that fails to do so, has penalty liability for all taxes not paid as a result of this income not being reported, so there is an obscure back door for entity liability. Also while beyond the scope of the OP, a few states do tax LLCs at the entity level even though the feds do not.